# Converting an non-linear problem to linear (linear programming)

Tags: linear-programming, constraints

I would like to use simplex on a non-linear programming problem and was wondering if there was a way to transform it to a linear constraint.

The problem is the following:

$$ \mathbb{min:} \space \space  {q^*}_{q<0}*{C^T_{q<0}} + {q^*}_{q>0}*{C^T_{q>0}} $$
$$ subject \space to: \space {\tau}_{\mathbb{lower\_limit}} \lt (p+q)*w^T < {\tau}_{\mathbb{upper\_limit}} $$

where:
$$ \text{q is the variable vector of length n and } $$ 
$$ q^*_{q<0} = q \text{ where q < 0 and 0 else (same definition for } q^*_{q>0} ) $$
$$ \text{C}_{q<0} \text{ is a cost vector of length n for when q <0} $$
$$ \text{C}_{q>0} \text{ is a cost vector of length n for when q >0} $$
$$ \text{w} \text{ is a weight vector of length n} $$
$$ \tau \text{ are scalars} $$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In linear/non linear programming you want to optimize a linear/non linear scalar function over a closed set. The closure hypothesis of the feasible set directly comes from the Weierstrass theorem. In the problem you propose: 1)the feasible set is not a closed set, since you use strict inequalities; 2) the objective function is not a scalar function, because you are taking the product between the column vector q and the row vector C and the result of this operation is a matrix; 3) in the constraints there is the same issue and p is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the costs are all positive you can use variable splitting:

$$\begin{align}
  \min & \sum_i c^+_i q^+_i + c^-_i q^-_i\\
       & q_i = q^+_i - q^-_i\\
       & q^+_i, q^-_i \ge 0  
\end{align}$$

Comment: I ended up doing the following:

$$.5 ( C^- + C^+)^T q + .5(C^- - C^+)^T |q|$$

Now we use the absolute value linearization trick and we get:

$$ .5(C^- + C^+)^T(T_1 + T_2) + .5(C^- - C^+)^T (T_1 - T_2) $$

Comment: I'm an idiot, ends up being the same solution.